# How to create a background mask from numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 3d numpy array image with a background of value 0 and true content with possible value of 0 to -1000. The true content is not necessarily at the middle of array. It can touch the edge of the array. But it is generally surrounded by the background. I want to create a mask that distinguish background as 0 and true content as 1. The logic should be like this: any pixel of value 0 AND without being surrounded by non-zero pixels is classified as background. Not surrounded should mean that there is no directly connecting path for that pixel to reach the background. So a whole patch of value 0 surrounded inside the true content should also be classified as true content.

I just can't think of any easy way to do this except running a for loop row-by-row, column-by-column.

Any idea is appreciated. Thanks.

One of the image slice along z-direction is like the following:
[image]

Comment: I think what you are looking for might be `Kernels` and `Convolutions`, they can be used to solve such problems. At least for 2D images, there are a lot of existing solutions in OpenCV for example. However, I don't know if they work for 3D cases as well.

Comment: @Szala Thx for your quick response. I will look up OpenCV. Do you have any keyword for that?

Comment: You mean, keyword for what?

Answer (score 0):

[`scipy.ndimage.minimum_filter`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.minimum_filter.html) may be able to solve your problem. The working example of a 2D array is as follows:

```
>>> r
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0, -1,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0, -9,  0,  0, -8],
       [ 0,  0, -1, -2,  0,  0,  0]])
>>> minimum_filter(r, 3, mode='constant') != 0
array([[False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True]])
```